# Flex wrapper makes TextInput be rendered outside it's parent

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to make a simple searchbar with rounded corners and an icon on the left, but everything is out of control when I try to use flexbox.

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

And this is my current code:

```
<ElevatedView style={[styles.searchBar, style]} elevation={elevation}>
   <View style={{ marginLeft: -10, marginRight: 10 }}>
      <Icon.Ionicons
         name="menu"
         size={26}
         style={{ height: 60 }}
         color="#54BCAE"
      />
   </View>
   <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 60 }}><TextInput {...rest} /></View>
</ElevatedView>
```

And the StyleSheets

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   searchBar: {
      marginTop: 65,
      marginBottom: 35,
      marginHorizontal: 20,
      borderRadius: 100,
      paddingHorizontal: 25,
      paddingVertical: 15,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
   }
});
```

I've tried literally EVERYTHING. I've looked into every similar (and in some cases, even identical) question here at the stackoverflow, github but nothing works. I've tried to set `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on everyone, I've tried to set a height (as it is stated in my code above) and width to the textInpu, but nothing works at all.

I also frequently get the result where the TextInput just disappears.

Help, I don't know what to do anymore, that's why I'm asking a new question.

Ps.: the `flexDirection: 'row'` is not the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I'VE SOLVED IT!

Well, the reason why everything was breaking is that I was applying `flex: 1` to the container, so the solution is to remove it:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   searchBar: {
      marginTop: 65,
      marginBottom: 35,
      marginHorizontal: 20,
      borderRadius: 100,
      paddingHorizontal: 25,
      paddingVertical: 15,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      flexDirection: 'row',
   }
});
```

Done!